# Time-span before answers can be submitted

Tags: feature-request, answers

When a new question appears and I go to answer it, I feel a terrible race with others, to get the first answer in. **Would it be an idea to have a certain period in which one can submit an answer, but it will not yet be visible?**

I'm thinking in terms of 2 or 3 minutes, after which all already-submitted answers become visible.

An example of a question where terribly short, sometimes incorrect answers are spewed just to have a fast word in: [Constructor in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693253/constructor-in-c-sharp#33693253)
I really feel the quality of answers would be improved if the 'race condition' was mitigated somewhat.

Comment: The same answers would still appear, just take longer for people to see them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. One of the best features of Stack Overflow is that you get answers quickly. If you hide answers for a few minutes there would be at least two drawbacks:

1. The asker wouldn't get their answer immediately.
2. *More* people would post duplicate answers because existing early answers wouldn't show up in the first few minutes.

That's not to say that we should condone "placeholder" answers. If people are posting very quick, incomplete (or otherwise incorrect) answers, simply downvote them.

Comment: 1. "I've been working on this problem for several hours before posting it to SO. I can wait two more minutes" - every asker on SO ever. 2. In my experience, duplicate answers are rarely 100% duplicates and it's in the difference that (sometimes) important nuances are made. This also gives one the opportunity to add those nuances to one's answers.

Comment: @steenbergh 1. I think you're wrong about that. 2. You see lots of exact duplicate answers in *exactly* the kind of question where you see lots of quick answers.

Comment: I quite often begin to type out an answer to find that in the time it took my slow self to write it out somebody has already written out an answer that contains all my information and some more, and then I end up just not posting it. Under your scenario I would end up posting most of these. Why exactly would that improve site quality (thats a catcha question, it wouldn't).

Comment: @steenbergh 1)WHAT?! just look at how many "PLEASE HELP ASAP" is added at the bottom of questions and you'll realize how false that is. 2) If you have a nuance about an answer, then post it even if there is a similar answer, no?