# Hide answers for my question from others

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

It will be great if we can hide some others Answers to our question for example in two or three days to see Other responses may be very different aspect and we can learn more about SO Q/A.

for me if i see a question have any answer, i am not enough enthusiasm to open it and take a look at it to answer.

If we can option to hide answers, may be better to make SO more better.

Comment: Why would hiding information make Stack Overflow - an attempt at creating a library of information - better?

Comment: @Makoto for me i want to see some different aspect of see a question and answer to it. I want to hide answers for example for 2 days to see complete possible great different others answers

Comment: But how does that make the site *better*?

Comment: after that period all answers will show to everyone and this make SO better to have more answers from different aspects not specially regular answers.

Comment: ... **But how does this make the site _better_?**

Comment: This is the first time I've seen any kind of feature request like this.  That suggests that there is insufficient demand to justify the work requred, even if it is a good idea, (which I'm fairly sure it is not).

Comment: after that period all the different answers make available to everyone, as now we probably have very wide range answers from kind SO users that answer it distinct with no more information about others answers.

Comment: Also, any kind of 'hiding' feature is likely to be abused, eg. by deadbeat students wishing to keep their copypasta activities out of their prof's view until after the homework is marked.

Comment: @MartinJames I want to express we can make SO richer from having wide range answers from different POV

Comment: @MartinJames its true, but i think many SO users know which question is homework and not answer to that cheaters.

Comment: @EsmaeelE and because answers are hidden, LOTS of people will work on the same thing. Sounds like a complete waste of time for all of them

Comment: @MartinJames I must add some option to solve cheating problem. we must give this authority to SO users that have more than 1k repo to avoid cheaters to misconduct.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310136/time-span-before-answers-can-be-submitted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are asking for a way to get answers from a different perspective, or more authoritative answers. There is already a way to do what you want: Use the [bounty system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

When you start a bounty you have multiple reasons to choose from:

[image: Bounty Selection]

You are also given a text box to describe in more detail what you are looking for, if these predefined reasons aren't enough.

Answer (score 17):

I understand that some users might be hesitant to answer a question that already has an answer (especially if that answer is from a user with high reputation). I agree that such hesitance may rob the site of some useful answers that might come from a different perspective.

I encourage these users to go ahead and post an answer anyway. We don't mind additional answers that provide different information.

However, the change you propose (allowing the hiding of answers for a few days) is a bad idea as:

- Other users may waste their time creating an answer that is essentially the same as one of the hidden ones.
- Users looking for an answer to this question are blocked from seeing it for a few days.

If you want to make it clear that you would like to see additional answers to the question then

- **Add a comment** to that effect either to the question or to an answer that you are not completely satisfied with.
- **Start a bounty** (as suggested by Andy in his answer).